# Splunk getting average TPS for each service

Tags: monitoring, data-analysis, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I am having an issue in Splunk Enterprise regarding getting average transactions per second for my scenario. In my case I want to, for a given time period,  get average transactions per second for each webservice request...

When I use following syntax its working fine:

```
index="index"  
| transaction "correlationId" keepevicted=true 
| timechart span=1s count as TPS 
| stats count avg(TPS)
```

...but then I get average transactions per second for all webservice requests.

If I try the below:

```
index="index"  
| transaction "correlationId"  keepevicted=true 
| timechart span=1s count as TPS 
| stats count avg(TPS) by "service"
```

...I dont get any result back

Is there something I am doing completely wrong here?

*All help and tips are much appreciated*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find a solution similar to one [I needed a while back](https://antipaucity.com/2020/08/18/how-to-timechart-possibly-better-than-timechart-in-splunk/#.Ya5TYlNOlAc) to be helpful - `timechart` without using [`timechart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart)

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp correlationId=* service=* earliest=-60m
| eval secs=strftime(_time, "%S")
| stats dc(correlationId) as TPS by secs service
| stats avg(TPS) as avgTPS by service
```

Or [`chart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/chart) instead of [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats):

```
| chart avg(TPS) as avgTPS by service
```

Answer (score 1):

`timechart` is a transforming command.  That means it does not pass all fields on to the next command so the `stats` command sees only 'count' and 'TPS' and not 'service'.  Try this:

```
index="index"  | transaction "correlationId"  keepevicted=true 
| timechart span=1s count as TPS by service | stats count avg(TPS) by service
```

Comment: Unfortunately no rows/results could be found after searching through 14205 matching events.